# Dot Matrix BOLD Printing in Java

Tags: java, printing

I have written a program to send raw (text only) data to the printer so that the Dot Matrix Printer will have to print the provided texts only instead of interpreting the input as image(which makes huge time to finish). Dot Matrix Printer is installed as the Generic Text Printer in my control panel.

Printer - **Wep 800 DX**  http://www.wepindia.com/Support/Support.aspx?ItemCode=MFD-0380

```
PrintService service = //My Dot Matrix Print Service
String input = "ESC E BOLD ESC F PRINTING\n";
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream((input.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(stream, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
try {
    job.print(doc, null);
} catch (PrintException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Codes
// ESC E - Turn Bold printing on
// ESC F - Turn Bold printing off
```

I get the list of codes from

http://www.lprng.com/DISTRIB/RESOURCES/PPD/epson.htm

http://webpages.charter.net/dperr/links/esc_p83.htm

The reason why I get the codes from epson is because somewhere I read these are implemented by most of other manufacturers and also I cant seem to find any Printer manual for my printer in manufacturer's website.

But when I run this program, the command codes `ESC E` and `ESC F` were printed in the paper instead of interpreting it as command codes.

Maybe I'm sending the command codes in wrong format. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update** - Got it working, Thanks @user2357112

```
char[] bold    = {0x001B, 0x0045};    // ESC, E
char[] unbold  = {0x001B, 0x0046};    // ESC, F
String input = new String(bold) + " BOLD " + new String(unbold) + " PRINTING\n";
```

output - **BOLD** PRINTING

Comment: Probably ESC means an escape character of some sort, not actually E S C and a space.

Comment: `ESC` definitely looks like it's supposed to be an ASCII escape character. (If you look at an [ASCII table](http://asciitable.com), you'll see escape is number 27, fitting with all those 27s in the pages you linked.)

Comment: @user2357112, so I've to provide the input as `char esc = 27; char e = 69; String input = esc + e +  " BOLD PRINTING";` ?

Comment: @user1354678: I would probably use hexadecimal escapes in the string literal. It avoids problems like having `esc + e` evaluated numerically.